# 404 Not Found nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu) in django application on ec2

Tags: python-3.x, django, nginx, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-20.04

I deployed my first django application on EC2 ubuntu 20.04. After deployment, I'm not able to assess any of the pages on the browser but in development all the pages are being displayed on the browser. Every single page is showing `404 Not Found nginx/1.18.0`. I have a working directory named `django` and the path to the directory is:

```
/var/www/html/django
```

The gunicorn is running properly `guni:gunicorn RUNNING   pid 121305, uptime 0:54:04.`. The content of `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` is

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name ip-address;
 location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
                #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location /static/ {
                autoindex on;
                alias /var/www/html/django/staticfiles/;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

        location /phpmyadmin/
         {
                 root /usr/share/;
                index index.php;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

}
```

The gunicorn.conf file has the following content:

```
[program:gunicorn]
Directory=/var/www/html/django
command=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/var/www/html/django/app.sock myproject.wsgi:application
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn.out.log
[group:guni]
programs:gunicorn
```

Gunicorn configuration seems to be accurate because whenever I check the status I have the following output:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-17-212:~$ sudo supervisorctl status
guni:gunicorn                    RUNNING   pid 291973, uptime 4:48:22
ubuntu@ip-172-31-17-212:~$
```

Please how do I fix this `404 not found nginx/1.18.0` error or is there any resource that will help?

Comment: This is not full nginx config. You will also need an app server like gunicorn.

Comment: Thanks @Shiv I added the complete conf. I have gunicorn and supervisor in place already.

Comment: Your nginx config is bad . It needs a section to reverse proxy to gunicorn

Comment: I think the command section of the gunicorn config file handles the functionality you meant

Comment: No command section of gunicorn will run the django code. nginx is used as a reverse proxy to connect to django via a port of socket to serve django's output.

Comment: @Shiv Please provide a sample of the code snippet you're talking about. If possible, provide it as an answer to the question and I'll accept it if it's actually the root cause of the 404

Comment: Suppose you are running gunicorn at port 5000 then you need something like 
```
location / {
    proxy_pass https://localhost:5000/;
}
```

Let me know what URL is giving you 404 and I will post full nginx config.

Comment: Thanks @Shiv. I have finally fix the issue. It was actually due to reverse proxy. But it didn't work by just adding proxy pass, I did that before. It's by adding Unix params and app.sock path to location/{} of sites-available and sites-enabled that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

root /var/www/html;

```
# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
http {
```

index index.html index.htm index.php index.nginx-debian.html;

```
server_name _;

location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
#
#       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
#       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#       # With php7.0-fpm:
#       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
#}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
#       deny all;
#}
location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
expires max;
log_not_found off;
```

Comment: It would help if you could explain how your answer addresses the question